# The word modular in the notion ``modular lattice''

Tags: lattice-theory, posets

Does the notion of modular lattice have anything to do with the meaning of the word modular, in either English  or mathematics?

A finite modular lattice is a finite graded lattice $L$ whose rank function $\rho$ satisfies 
$$
\rho(x)+\rho(y)=\rho(x\wedge y)+\rho(x\vee y)
$$
for all $x,y\in L$. It has some equivalent definitions such like a finite lattice such that
$$
x\vee (y\wedge z)=(x\vee y)\wedge z 
$$
for all $x,y,z\in L$ such that $x\le z$.
The word modular means employing or involving a module or modules as the basis of design or construction in English, and relating to modulus in mathematics.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice: "Modular lattices arise naturally in algebra and in many other areas of mathematics. In these scenarios, modularity is an abstraction of the 2nd Isomorphism Theorem. For example, the subspaces of a vector space (and more generally the submodules of a module over a ring) form a modular lattice." I think this is the explanation of the name.

Comment: @SamHopkins The wikipedia article you link to also has a [history section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice#History), which gives more details about the origin of the name!

Comment: In general algebra, a modular lattice does not always come with a grading. It satisfies a modular law, which was observed by Dedekind to hold for (essentially) lattices of normal subgroups of a group.  You might search for the history of modular lattices to answer your question. Gerhard "Dedekind Thought Differently About Them" Paseman, 2019.01.23.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300013/the-origins-of-modular-and-moduli) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191312/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-modular-in-different-areas) about the relationships between various meanings of "modular" in mathematics.

Comment: @SamHopkins Yes that answers it.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks for the sources. It looks the question does have a historic answer in Richard Dedekind's work.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Thanks for sharing the non-universality of the grading condition though it is true for finite modular lattices.